# Some problems in additive functions.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let f be a function that satisfies $\forall x\in R: f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$ . 
I'm thinking about equivalnce 
$$f(x_0)=0 \Leftrightarrow x_0=0$$ 
Where f(x) $\neq 0$. It's true of course if $f$ is a continous function (because then $f(x)=f(1)x$), but I do not know if it is going to work if $f$ is not continous.
I managed to prove the following equivalence: 
$f(x_0)=0 \Longleftrightarrow x_0=0 \Longleftrightarrow f$ is an injective function(for f(x) $\neq 0$), but it does not help me so much. It is also hard to even draw not continous additive functions, because they are not continous in any point.

Comment: $f(x)=0$ is continuous and it get the value zero even when $x_0\not = 0$. You can easily prove that $f(0)=0$ because $f(0)+f(0)=f(0+0)=f(0)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation The non-continuous functions are basically a collection of many different linear functions, one for each scaled copy of $\Bbb Q$ (I believe they require the axiom of choice to construct).

Comment: @Arthur They do require more than ZF. If the functions are measurable, then they are linear, and there exist models for ZF in which all functions are measurable.

Comment: @TheoBendit Obviously they don't require the _full_ strength of the AoC. But among the axioms to add to ZF which guarantees that nonlinear solutions exist, AoC is definitely the most commonly used one.

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=0$$ is a continuous and additive function.

But

$$f(x_0)=0\iff x_0=0$$ does not hold.